# Python PyAudio Как обновить список микрофонов при повторном подключении

Tags: python, windows, pyaudio

WIndows 10. Python.

При работе с pyaudio выставляю индекс микрофона = 1. Гоняю цикл с микрофоном. При отключении внешнего микрофона от ноутбука перехватываю ошибку и продолжаю гонять цикл, в котором подхватывается все также микрофон с индексом = 1 (который теперь не внешний, а уже встроенный). Но данные в программе относительно информации о микрофоне обновить не могу. Вот так получаю список микрофонов:

```
def get_mics_list():
    mics = []
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
        if p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'] == 'Microsoft Sound Mapper - Input':
            pass
        elif p.get_device_info_by_index(i)['name'] == 'Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output':
            break
        else:
            mics.append(p.get_device_info_by_index(i))
    return mics
```

На выходе имею список словарей с информацией о каждом микрофоне в системе. Но при изменении микрофона в системе (например отключении микрофона), обновить информацию, используя эту функцию, не могу. Возвращает тот же список словарей, что и был до отключения микрофона. Почему так?

Comment: Вы по новой вызываете get_device_count()? Я имею ввиду что бы получить актуальную информацию.

Comment: @Александр да (заново вызываю get_mics_list(), в котором вызывается get_device_count()) 
 UPD : Проверил отдельно функцию get_device_count(). Результат тот же. Ощущение, что программа замораживает значения после старта. Ака предвычислила и забыла

Comment: Вы найдите индексы интересующих вас устройст и обращайтесь по индексу

Comment: У вас функция должна получить список микрофонов?

Comment: Там что за дичь с pass и break?

Comment: PyAudio гарантировано вернёт вам устройство по индексу

Comment: Покажите код где вы пытаетесь увидеть включен или выключен микрофон.

Comment: @Александр при стандартном запросе p.get_device_count() вам вернут все аудиоустройства (и драйверы в том числе) в системе. В списке устройств есть логические разделители, которые я указал в условии. Моя функция - чисто обертка для вычленения записывающих устройств из общего списка. Проблема в том, что сама по себе функция p.get_device_count() не может обновить данные после старта программы.

Comment: @Александр Можете убедиться в этом, поставив цикл с вызовом списка устройств и засыпанием на несколько десятков секунд. За это время отсоедините (отключите в системе, если встроенный) микрофон. На новом витке цикла и повторном вызове функции вы увидите, что список аудиоустройств не поменялся.

Comment: Я отключил встроеный микрофон и удалил его из системы в диспетчере устройств. Но браузер как и другие программы спокойно работали с микрофоном, так что думаю здесь дело не в PyAudio.

Comment: @Александр о том и речь. PyAudio или конкретно сам питон не в состоянии обновить данные по системе после старта скрипта

Comment: Вы прочтите внимательно мой последний комментарий, дело не в Python или в PyAudio.

Comment: @Александр, проверьте ситуацию конкретно с питоном. Другие программы и браузеры с большой долей вероятности обновляют информацию по устройствам после их от/подключения в системе. Ситуация описанная вами работает и у меня, в отличие от питона

Comment: Возможно что информация об устройствах получается только при создании объекта класса PyAudio. Но это как то не правильно.

Comment: @Александр, к сожалению и этот вариант не прокатил. Даже в новом объекте класса, созданного по таймеру, специально чтобы успеть подключить устройство, все равно имеет те же данные об устройствах что и первый объект класса